# Change Python script parameters from another Python script

Tags: python, regex

I have a main-script from which I want to make a couple of temporary copies, with slight changes in each of the copies.

`main.py` could look like this:

```py
import NumPy as np
import module
import bar

...

foo = bar(label='C2H4', point=(1,0))

atoms = 'H4'
template = read('template.t')
size = template.lengths()

n = 4
alpha = 0.5
batch_size = 256 // (n * alpha)

dct = {
    '1': [1, 2],
    '6': [3, 4],
}

kwargs = {
    'dict': dct,
    'size': size,
    'scale': size[0] / 10,
}

...

module(atoms, kwargs, foo)
module.run()
```

In another script, called `parameter_search.py`, I make the copy and change the parameters by running through each line in `main.py`, searching for what should be changed.

If the variable is found, a regex-command splits the line, and then changes the float (I'm not the best at regexes, so this could probably use some work):

```py
import re
import fileinput
import os from shutil import copyfile

def is_num(var):
    try:
        float(var)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def replace(filename, var_expr, new_val):
    found = False
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1):
        if var_expr in line:
            if not found:
                found = True
                lst = re.split('(=|:|,)', line)
                for i, char in enumerate(lst):
                    if is_num(char):
                        lst[i] = str(new_val)
                line = "".join(lst)
            else:
                raise NameError(f'{var_expr} ambigous')
        print(line, end="")
    if not found:
        raise NameError(f'{var_expr} not found in {filename}')


N = [10, 20]
alpha = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
foo = [bar(alpha=1), baz()]

for n in N:
    for a in alpha:
        for i, f in enumerate(foo):
            newfile = 'main'
            newfile += f'_n{n}'
            newfile += f'_a{a}'
            newfile += f'_f{i}'
            newfile += '.py'

            copyfile('main.py', newfile)

            replace(newfile, 'n=', n)
            replace(newfile, 'alpha=', use_n)
            replace(newfile, 'foo = ', f)
```

This gives decent results, but problems arise if several variables are on the same line, such as `bar(label='C2H4', point=(1, 0))` or the variable is a part of a dict as `kwargs`, the parameter is a string, a function or some other weird variable.

Is it possible to make something like `replace()` that is more general or in some other way makes this possible?

Comment: I suggest you learn more about regexes, this can be pretty neatly solved using them. You can test it on this website https://regex101.com/ until your regex matches everything you want. May I ask why you would want to modify the script itself instead of passing the values as an argument to a function inside said script?

Comment: I probably should study regexes somewhat more, I just don't really understand them and isn't the only problem here. Normally i would pass the arguments themselves, but i actually have many main-files - all of them doing something different using Reinforcement Learning

Comment: I understand, start off by listing every possible format of the parameters and I could then help you out constructing and explaining the regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let me make a few assumptions here:

1. The parameters assignment happens only once in the .py script and it is also the first occurence of the parameter name.
2. There are exactly two ways to declare a parameter: as a single variable `par = value` or inside a dictionary `{'par' : value}` (with single or double quotes).

You can then use the `re.sub` function to directly substitute the value of the assignment, using what is called *capture groups*:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

> Return the string obtained by replacing the **leftmost non-overlapping occurrences** of
>   pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found,
>   string is returned unchanged. repl can be a string or a function; if
>   it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n
>   is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a
>   carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes of ASCII letters are
>   reserved for future use and treated as errors. Other unknown escapes
>   such as \& are left alone. **Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced
>   with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern**.

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

So, your function to set a new value for a given parameter name could look like this:

```
def replace_parameter_value_if_found(string, parameter, new_value):
    return new_string = re.sub("([\'\"]?"+parameter+"[\'\"]?\s*[=:]\s*)[\.\w]*", "\1"+new_value, string)
```

Now, let's break it down:

```
"([\'\"]?"+parameter+"[\'\"]?\s*[=:]\s*)[.\w]*"
```

- Stuff enclosed in `()` is called a capture group - it can be
  referenced later.
- Stuff enclosed in `[]` matches any of those characters inside (the backslash serves as an escape character)
- `?` is a quantifier matching zero or one occurrence of what it immediately succeeds
- `*` is a quantifier matching any number of occurrences of what it immediately succeeds, including zero
- any literal string matches that string
- `\s` and `\w` match any whitespace and any word character (a-z0-9), respectively

So, say the parameter was `'alpha'`, the regex pattern becomes

```
"([\'\"]?alpha[\'\"]?\s*[=:]\s*)[\.\w]*"
```

and reads like this:

1. Open capture group 1
2. Match a single ' or " or neither (because of the ?)
3. Match the literal word `alpha`
4. Match a single ' or " or neither
5. Match any number of white space characters
6. Match a single = or :
7. Close capture group 1 (it now contains `alpha=` or `'alpha':` or some variation of it)
8. Match any number of word characters or periods (this is what we will be replacing)

All this will then be replaced with what's in capture group 1, followed by the new value, hence:

```
"\1"+new_value
```

The string can be the entirety of the .py script, also keep in mind that what you are passing to the function are strings and they can be whatever you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For clarifications sake, perhaps an edit is needed to ask these questions: If i wanted to change one string to another (`foo='bar'` -> `foo='not_bar'`) should I just modify the regex to `"([\'\"]?"+parameter+"[\'\"]?\s*[=:]\s*)[\'\"]?[\.\w]*[\'\"]?"`? Also, if I wanted to make it possible to alter function-parameters or some other weird parameters (`foo='bar()'` -> `foo='not_bar(a=1)'` or `scale = size[0] / 10` -> `scale = size[0] / 5`), would this be possible in some way?

Comment: After having actually played around with it, I seem to not reeaally understand the use of both regex and re.sub as well as i thought.. If I try to use this, I get a lot of `\x0`/`\x01`-bytes in my new scripts. Perhaps you could make a fully running implementation of your answer?

Comment: @AndersBB Yes, something like that. Or you can just put `.*\n` after the group that captures the name up to the equals sign to replace anything that is after that up until the end of a line with anything in the `new_value` parameter. The new value can be anything if it is in a string form, so it shloud now cover all possible cases (but with the requirement that the assignment has to be on a line on its own).

Comment: I'll try to debug a running example later today if I have time and energy. It would help if you could supply all the possible forms of parameters to be replaced.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the types of parameters in `main.py`. Not all variables should be altered, but it would be nice to have a way to alter one-line parameters such as floats, strings, lists, tuples and expressions (for example `256 // (n * alpha)`). Preferentially in that order